# How to print number after a delay in JS

Tags: javascript

It's beginner's question. I'm trying to understand setTimeout. I want to print each number after a delay of 2 seconds. However, I can only delay the whole function, not the numbers. Can anyone tell me how to do it?

```js
function print() {
  for (let i = 10; i >= 0; i--) {
    console.log(i);
  }
}

setTimeout(print, 2000);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another approach is using `setInterval`. It is more natural for this task then `setTImeout`.

```js
let i = 10;
const interval = setInterval(() => {
  console.log(i);
  i--;
  if(i === 0){
    clearInterval(interval);
  }
}, 2000);
```

Comment: Thanks azendh it looks easier to follow for me.

Comment: Some typing mistake `i --` should be `i--` and `200` should be `2000`

Answer (score 7):

You need to use the `setTimeout` inside the `print` method (*inside the `for`*), and give a different delay for each iteration.

```js
function print() {
  for (let i = 10; i >= 1; i--) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(i);
    }, 2000 * (10 - i));
  }
}

print();
```

Comment: It works but I don't understand (10 - i)  part. I know 2000 is the delay for each but what is the logic in these bracket (so i= 10 in the beginning, so 10 - 10 = 0, then 10 - 9 = 1 etc) but it doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: @TomDev it's so that each timeout waits 2000 seconds longer than the previous. Remember that setTimeout() does not actually delay. The whole for loop will be executed immediately with no internal delays.

Answer (score 3):

setTimeout here will delay all the function and if I get what you want to do is to print each number in 2s delay.
ill recommend using [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and [async](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) function.
here is a solution with only setTimeout

```js
function print(i){
  console.log(i)
  if(i>0){
    setTimeout(()=>{print(i-1)},2000)
  }
}
print(10)
```

Comment: You guys offered me so many solutions. Thanks a lot. I couldn't think up a single one.

Comment: @TomDev It's a power of asking in right platform

Comment: Sometimes they bounce the questions as well  ;) or send me to solutions that are too hard to grasp for the beginner or are not accurate.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to do this by [`setInterval`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp)

```js
let limit = 10
console.log('start')
let interval = setInterval(()=>{
console.log(limit--)
if(!limit){
  clearInterval(interval)
  console.log('end')
}
},2000)
```

With immediate start from 10 without 2 seconds wait.

```js
let limit = 10
console.log('start')
const executeLogic = () =>{
  console.log(limit--)
}
executeLogic()
let interval = setInterval(()=>{
  executeLogic()
  if(!limit){
    clearInterval(interval)
    console.log('end')
  }
},2000)
```